# continuous injective function on an interval I that is neither increasing nor decreasing function

Tags: calculus

give an example of a continuous injective  function on an interval I that is neither increasing nor deacreasing function, I can´t think of an example for this function I really need your help

Comment: By the intermediate value theorem, no such functions exist.

Answer (score 0):

A complex-valued function, mapping a continuous real interval *I* onto a continuous line or surface in the complex plane. For instance, $f(x)=e^{ix}$, with $I=[0,2\pi)$.